# batch files: windows eqvivalent

Tags: bash, batch-file

in `bash` I have

```
echo `date``time``bla-bla-bla`
```

how can we do the same for windows in batch file? I mean back quoted command inline

Comment: This question is a bit vague and will likely only lead you to either wrong, hard to maintain or ugly code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In batch there is no advanced command substitution.

You could however do:

```
FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %%I IN ('echo %date%') DO echo %%I
```

(use single percent signs if in interactive mode, double percent signs in a .bat or .cmd).

If you want backquotes:

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%I IN (`echo %date%`) DO echo %%I
```

So:

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%I IN (`bla bla bla`) DO SET blablaresult=%%I
echo %date%%time%%blablaresult%
```

Comment: o.O That's probably the most convoluted way I've ever seen to just say `echo %date%`. You even went painfully sure that the result is *exactly* the same.

Comment: @Joey: using `echo` in the end is just provided as an example, but this is to show that you can manipulate `%%I`.

Comment: @vinnitu: see last lines of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can get at date and time values by using predefined dynamic variables %date% and %time% - no need to use a command. You can combine that with a FOR loop to process the output of the 'bla bla bla' command.

```
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('"bla bla bla"') do @echo %date% %time% %%A
```

If run from the command line (not within a batch file) then %%A becomes %A.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this in the command line....

```
@echo %date% %time% bla bla bla
```

Comment: sorry, I misunderstood your vague question.